# Property or indexer cannot be used in this context - Error in Unity v2019.3.4f1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

[image: code]

When I write the code for showing score according to distance on the `z axis` on the Text,it shows this message.
I wrote the line:

```
scoreText.text = player.position.z.toString("0");
```

When Debugging the Error is:

```
The property or indexer 'TextInputBaseField<string>.text' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible [Assembly-CSharp]
```

Please help me I have all over the Internet.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not big it was just my editor's problem.I am using Visual Studio Code which has a recurring problem in the version 1.1.4 i just had to downgrade it to version 1.1.3.
If anyone els has this problem do the same.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you are using the wrong UI Elements.

Change line 4 from

```
using UnityEngine.UIElements;
```

to

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

and then change type of `scoreText` to `Text`, so line 8 will be:

```
public Text scoreText;
```

Don't forget to assign `Text` in editor!

**But if i'm wrong, and you are using the correct [UIElements](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.TextField.html)**

just change

```
scoreText.text
```

to

```
scoreText.value
```

Comment: @ARK69 what exactly happened after you accomplished first variant?